# Show dividing lines between horizontal bars on highcharts graph

Tags: highcharts

Hi I'd like a 1px gray line in between each horizontal bar.... (keeping the bars the same thickness)

http://jsfiddle.net/gpaosxwe/1/

I've had a brief try of

```
grid
```

and

```
tick
```

though I might have overlooked something...

Comment: By line you mean space between bars or add extra line (i.e gray) in current space between bards?

Comment: yes an extra gray line between them thanks

Comment: BTW what I actually wanted to do was have zebra striping - http://jsfiddle.net/gpaosxwe/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the following combination of properties:

```
categories:[],
gridLineWidth:1,
tickInterval:1,
tickmarkPlacement:'between',
```

(tickmarkPlacement is key, which only works for categorized axes)

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/gpaosxwe/6/

References:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickmarkPlacement
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.gridLineWidth
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.gridLineColor
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval

Comment: Hi I was also wondering how to change the color of the lines - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `borderWidth`, `pointPadding` and `groupPadding`. You could do something like :

```
plotOptions: {
      bar: {
         borderWidth: 1, //Define a border of 1px to each bars
         pointPadding: 0, //Define space between two bars
         groupPadding: 0, // Define space between each value groups
         ...                        
      },
      ...
}
```

See [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gpaosxwe/5/).

Comment: Hi I want to keep the bars the same thickness and have a thin gray line between them